# Resumable File Downloading/Uploading in Android

Tags: java, android, http, file-upload, download

I have been working on an android project in which I have to download/upload few files via HTTP. I was wondering if there is a way to have resumable downloads/uploads for the files. As in, if my file is being downloaded or uploaded and there is a subtle internet choke for very minimal time (this sometimes corrupts the file and the process is stopped and next time it starts from 0 ) the downloading/uploading is paused and once the internet is back again on my device, the downloading/uploading starts from the same point where it was stopped at so that the file does not get corrupted and the process does not start from 0.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality in android/Java ? Please do let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html itself doesn't provide such ability to load file in chunks. [FileUpload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp) is simple object which works with file as whole and so sends it from scratch. To fulfill your requirements you need more sophisticated client/server relations. Java Applet is good candidate to do so on the client side and server side is trivial. However you need to implement some protocol (like handshake, start to send file, continue from some location, validation) and this is not an easy task. Even most commonly protocols (for example ftp) don't provide such ability. And even when you create all this stuff it will be compatible only with itself. Is it really worth all the efforts? Common answer is - no. That's the reason why we don't see such approach in the wild.

Comment: why it's not worthy effort as most of the the that deals with this kind of stuff implements the resumable file upload let's say for whatsApp

Comment: Nobody says it's impossible. It is quite possible. Torrent is good example. It's even better - it not resumes - it uploads in chunks. It is good implementation of this idea. But does this functionality exist in raw android/Java? No. Is it worth to implement in such application like whatsApp? It's up to whatsApp to decide. Is it worth to do it for your own application? It's up to you. Is it worth to make it standard? You can try to implement and convince community to use it. It maybe true. But, I had said,  we don't see such approach in the wild.